# transdermal estrogen use sans progesterone & endometrial and breast cancer risk?

Tags: cancer, endocrinology, gynecology

To what extent does transdermal estrogen use, without co-use of progesterone, increase endometrial and breast cancer risk?

How does risk, if it exists correlate with years of use?